# Excel VBA - Pivot Table - variable in changeing output data

Tags: vba, excel

```
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna1").PivotFields( _
    "[Period_BO].[Period].[Year]").ClearAllFilters
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna1").PivotFields( _
    "[Period_BO].[Period].[Year]").CurrentPageName = _
    "[Period_BO].[Period].[Day].&[2.0170526E7]"
```

I build some buttons to excel sheet that update data from database and are using in daily reports. This is code above that work, but I need to change it to use specify data from variable instead of [2.0170526E7] and have problem. I was trying different methods, but is sense that I cannot use variable in this code. My question is why? Or how I should do it.

start:

```
  Dim wturaj As String
     wturaj = Format(Now() - 3, "yyyymmdd")
```

case1:

```
    wturaj = Left(wturaj, 1) & "." & Mid(wturaj, 2, 7) & "E7"   '2.0170526E7
```

case2:

```
    wturaj = Left(wturaj, 1) & "." & Mid(wturaj, 2, 7) & "E7"
    wturaj = "[" & wturaj & "]"   '[2.0170526E7]
```

case3:

```
    wturaj = Format(Now() - 3, "dd, mmm, yyyy")   '26, May, 2017
```

case4:

```
    wturaj = "26, May, 2017"   'hardcoded 26, May, 2017
```

end:

```
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna1").PivotFields( _
            "[Period_BO].[Period].[Year]").ClearAllFilters
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna1").PivotFields( _
            "[Period_BO].[Period].[Year]").CurrentPageName = _
            "[Period_BO].[Period].[Day].&wturaj"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you fully, but I think for the final line, just take the variable _outside_ the `"` speech marks, otherwise it's treated as text. So the final line of your example goes to `"[Period_BO].[Period].[Day].&" & wturaj` assuming case 2. The 2nd `&` _concatenates_ the variable onto the end of the string

Comment: Thanks it help. It is looks like I don't exactly understand construction of that action